# Need to modify my Regex to ignore iframe tags

Tags: c#, regex, markdown

Hi I have a free text editor for blog posts on my website with C# as code behind.  I use the following regular expression to strip all HTML tags out of the post for security:

```
Regex.Replace(value, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

However I now have a requirement to allow the embedding of youtube videos, which use an iframe, for example:

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ttBhGiuMUmU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Could someone help me modify this regex to allow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<(?!/?iframe)(.|\n)*?>
```

The `(?!/?iframe)` is a negative lookahead, that checks that the `<` is not followed by an `iframe` or `/iframe`.

I tested [online here on regexr](http://regexr.com?2tnt6)

Comment: The "/" needed to be escaped else it will give error. So the regex should be `<(?!\/?iframe)(.|\n)*?>`. This is the [online demo](http://regexr.com/3ggfl)